# SOAP - best practice for method parameters

Tags: soap, soa

Is it better to have a method like this:

#1 `void AddPerson(Person p);`

or

#2 `void AddPerson(int id, string lastName, string firstName);`

Explain.

The one issue I noticed is I cannot point my web browser to AddPerson and test for #1, but I can for #2.

Comment: You have tagged this question with SOAP - how would you test this with a browser, as SOAP would usually include XML in the request and response?

Comment: It is not easy to test SOAP using either a Web Browser or curl, you'd better use SOAPUI in order to create tests and mocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what **ahus1** said, creating a separate Person.xsd XML schema is almost always a good idea, because this way you could import this Person.xsd into other XML schemas such as Invoice.xsd, creating a common language in order to describe your business.

Also, it makes it more simple to orchestrate services, imagine that you might have a given customer atribute into Invoice that is actually from Person Type. This way you could assign the customer value to other Person elements in just one step instead of having to copy all Person attributes in each step.

You may find at [Canonical Schema](http://www.soapatterns.org/canonical_schema.php) SOA Pattern, good information about the benefits of this approach.

Comment: In addition in your service names avoid weak (general) verbs like _add_ or _process_ and use strong (specific) verbs like **register**, **submit** or **create** from business domain terminology e.g. CreditCustomer, OnlineCustomer. Usecase naming conventions will serve your well in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

if you pass a person instead of the different elements, it will be easier for you when you enhance the Person in the future for example with a date of birth: your method names stay the same, you just enhance your domain model fill or read the date of birth where you need it.

Also you will find that as soon as you get a nested objects (if you want to add i.e. an address), a Person instead of the elements will give a uniform way for your methods.

Best regards,
Alexander.